# Bluetooth on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Super noob question. Apologies in advance. I've spent hours and hours trying to find what I'm looking for in the forums. But I don't know exactly what it is that I don't know.

I was asked to make an app to replace a piece of hardware. Right now there are 2 pcbs with bluetooth modules on them. One sends a signal to the other. The 2nd device lights up LEDs and beeps after receiving the proper signal. That's it. They want an app to replace the 2nd device. So android phones need to be able to pair, and receive that signal. They made the boards without the knowledge that the app would be created.

Do they people making the boards need to code something on their end to allow android to discover it? Or Can I force android to see/pair their device? Right now it does not even show up on androids bluetooth list. It does show up on LightBlue. But I cannot pair.

I realize this is a very complex thing. I fully admit I am not knowledgeable and really should NOT be the one making this app lol. But this is where I am. Any help at all is super appreciated. One day I will be as powerful as you. But for now, I ask dumb questions.

Thanks!!

Comment: `But I don't know exactly what it is that I don't know.` this is a wise statement :)

Comment: Forget about the Android part for now. Just investigate the used protocol. Read this for first ideas: http://nilhcem.com/iot/reverse-engineering-simple-bluetooth-devices

Comment: Bluetooth Advertising Beacon 
bcnBeaconAdvData = { 
0x1B, /* length */ 
0xFF, /* type */ 
{0x00,0x01}, /* mafID*/ 
{0xBE,0xAC}, /* Beacon Code 0xBEAC*/ 
/* Beacon ID */ 
{ 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, \ 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, \ 
0xB0, 0xB0, 0xB0, 0xB0}, 
/* The Beacon's measured RSSI at 1 meter distance in dBm */ 
0xC3, /* 0xC3 is -61dBm */ 
0x00 /* reserved */ 
};

Comment: I was sent that and this: Bytes Data Result 
0 Length 0x1B (Bluetooth Spec) 
1 Type 0xFF (Bluetooth Spec) 
2 - 3 Manufacturer ID 0x0001 
4 - 5 Beacon Code 0xBEAC 
6 - 11 UUID/MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00 
12 Compression Depth OK - Buzzer 0 & 1, Beep on change 
13 Compression LED - Red/Green See LED states below 
14 Compression Freq. LED - Red/Green See LED states below 
15 Pair Mode 0x00 = No, 0x35 = Yes 
16 Calibration Mode 0x00 = No, 0x01 = Yes 
17 - 25 Not Used 
26 RSSI (Bluetooth Spec) 
27 Reserved 0x00 (Bluetooth Spec)

Comment: No idea if that is what the IOT reverse engineering is pulling but it looks the same to me